Being in translation - ser
Is the translation of "being" below fine?
English
Our being śeṣa to the Lord
we share in common with non-sentient things
but we are śeṣas in the special sense also of being His servants (dāsāh).

Español
Nuestro ser Śeṣa para el Señor
Compartimos en común con cosas no sensibles
Pero somos Śeṣas en el sentido especial también de ser sus siervos (dāsāh).

Sí. Difícil de entender el significado de todo el texto, sin embargo.

Yes, "being" is translated as "ser".
The one I cannot find a good meaning for is "sésa"
"Nuestro ser śeṣa para el Señor
tenemos cosas en común con cosas (¿criaturas?) no sensibles
pero somos śeṣas en el sentido especial también de ser sus siervos (dāsāh)."

"tenemos cosas en común con cosas" → "tenemos en común con cosas"?

Sí, puede ser, "tenemos algo en común con cosas (seres / entes) no sensibles".

Existe una idea metafísica de que todo vibra, hasta las piedras, de ahí que la idea de "cosas no sensibles" no sería válida según esa filosofía. Que no podamos percibir que algo "siente" (es sensible) no necesariamente significa que no sea "sensible"
